# Bulk load from csv w/ openrowset & formatfile is doubling hyphen (dash)

Tags: sql-server, csv

A SQL Server database zip code column is defined as `varchar(10)`.

When using

```
SELECT ZIP 
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'zip.csv', FORMATFILE='zip.fmt')
```

everything is loading fine into my database, but zip codes that look like `12345-1234` in the csv end up as `12345--123` in the database.

Format file is (uses more fields, but only zip is giving me a problem):

```
12.0
7
1 SQLCHAR 0 0 "," 1   SalesOrder        Latin1_General_BIN
2 SQLCHAR 0 0 "," 93  ShipAddress1      Latin1_General_BIN
3 SQLCHAR 0 0 "," 94  ShipAddress2      Latin1_General_BIN
4 SQLCHAR 0 0 "," 95  ShipAddress3      Latin1_General_BIN
5 SQLCHAR 0 0 "," 96  ShipAddress3Loc   Latin1_General_BIN
6 SQLCHAR 0 0 "," 97  ShipAddress4      Latin1_General_BIN
7 SQLCHAR 0 0 ",\r\n" 99  ShipPostalCode    Latin1_General_BIN
```

Why this strange doubling of the hyphen or dash?

Comment: What does your formatfile look like? I'm guessing the issue lies within that.